# Access nested state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following object in my state and I'm trying to access the bracket and entries properties.

[image]

This is how I try to access the attributes, however I just get "cannot access attribut of undefined" errors

```
  function App () {
  const [ladder, setLadder] = useState({})

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchMyAPI () {
      try {
        const res = await axios.get(
          'data/wow/pvp-season/27/pvp-leaderboard/3v3?namespace=dynamic-eu&locale=en_US&access_token=12345'
        )
        setLadder(res)
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
      }
    }
    fetchMyAPI()
  }, [])

  return (
    <>
      {console.log(ladder.data.bracket)} // cannot access bracket of undefined ...
      {console.log(ladder.data.entries[0])} // cannot access entries of undefined ...
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: The first time the component is rendered, `ladder` will be an empty object (`useState({})`), i.e. `ladder.data` doesn't exist. It only exists after `axios.get` is done. So if you do a simple check first whether `ladder.data` exists you'll be fine.

Comment: You're trying to access `ladder.data.bracket` before the `ladder` gets the data from the request, so `ladder.data` is `undefined`, you can use this: `{ladder.data && console.log(ladder.data.bracket)}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return (
    <>
      {console.log(ladder?.data?.bracket)}
      {console.log(ladder?.data?.entries[0])}
    </>
  )
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

You can also use the logical AND operator

```
return (
    <>
      {console.log(ladder && ladder.data &&  ladder.data.bracket)}
      {console.log(ladder && ladder.data && Array.isArray(ladder.data.entries) && ladder.data.entries[0])}
    </>
  )
```

You can also adapt the initial value of ladder and let the render code unchanged

```
const [ladder, setLadder] = useState({
  data: {
    entries: []
  }
})
```

Or even lodash get function!

```
return (
    <>
      {console.log(_.get(ladder, "data.bracket"))}
      {console.log(_.get(ladder, "data.entries[0]"))}
    </>
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

You're getting that error because on the first render (which occur on load up of the component), the state variable `ladder` is an empy object. Only after the data is fetched, the variable is updated. So You can "render nothing" as long as `ladder.data` is `undefined` by checking the value before accessing it:

```
  function App () {
  const [ladder, setLadder] = useState()

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchMyAPI () {
      try {
        const res = await axios.get(
          'data/wow/pvp-season/27/pvp-leaderboard/3v3?namespace=dynamic-eu&locale=en_US&access_token=12345'
        )
        setLadder(res)
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
      }
    }
    fetchMyAPI()
  }, [])

  return (
    <>
      {console.log(ladder && ladder.data.bracket)}
      {console.log(ladder && ladder.data.entries[0])}
    </>
  )
}
```

Notice that I've changed the initial value to `undefined` instead of `{}`. If you are willing to remain the initial value an empty object for some reason, you can use `lodash` (for instance) to check if the object is empty before rendering:

```
const _ = require('lodash');

  return (
    <>
      {console.log(!_.isEmpty(ladder) && ladder.data.bracket)}
      {console.log(!_.isEmpty(ladder) && ladder.data.entries[0])}
    </>
  )
```

Comment: Ladder is initialised as {}, the problem is ladder.data. ladder && ladder.data.bracket will fail too

Comment: @AlHill You're right! missed that initial value of {}..

I'll edit